# PHP and XML attributes

Tags: php, xml-parsing

I have searched here and the rest of the net and I can't find any help with this.

I have a response from a curl_exec.  The response is an XML string called $output.

```
echo '<pre>' . htmlentities($output) . '</pre>';
```

Gives:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RESPONSE>
  <FIELDS>
    <FIELD KEY="status">1</FIELD>
    <FIELD KEY="auth_code">DEMO43</FIELD>
    <FIELD KEY="auth_response">APPROVED</FIELD>
    <FIELD KEY="avs_code">X</FIELD>
    <FIELD KEY="cvv2_code"> </FIELD>
    <FIELD KEY="order_id">12345678900015</FIELD>
    <FIELD KEY="reference_number">47210</FIELD>
    <FIELD KEY="error" />
    <FIELD KEY="available_balance" />
    <FIELD KEY="is_partial">0</FIELD>
    <FIELD KEY="partial_amount">0</FIELD>
    <FIELD KEY="partial_id" />
    <FIELD KEY="original_full_amount" />
    <FIELD KEY="outstanding_balance">0</FIELD>
  </FIELDS>
</RESPONSE>
```

I need to pull out specific information, for example, the value associated with "auth_code"  (ie: DEMO43).

After many hours of fruitless searching, I need help.  How do I get this data into an associative array like:

```
$array = ('status'=>'1','auth_code'=>'DEMO43' ... etc) ?
```

Comment: Use `simplexml_load_string()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this

```
$string = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RESPONSE>
  <FIELDS>
    <FIELD KEY="status">1</FIELD>
    <FIELD KEY="auth_code">DEMO43</FIELD>
    <FIELD KEY="auth_response">APPROVED</FIELD>
    <FIELD KEY="avs_code">X</FIELD>
    <FIELD KEY="cvv2_code"> </FIELD>
    <FIELD KEY="order_id">12345678900015</FIELD>
    <FIELD KEY="reference_number">47210</FIELD>
    <FIELD KEY="error" />
    <FIELD KEY="available_balance" />
    <FIELD KEY="is_partial">0</FIELD>
    <FIELD KEY="partial_amount">0</FIELD>
    <FIELD KEY="partial_id" />
    <FIELD KEY="original_full_amount" />
    <FIELD KEY="outstanding_balance">0</FIELD>
  </FIELDS>
</RESPONSE>';


$ARR_OUTPUT = array();

$dom = new DOMDocument();
$dom->loadXML($string);
$searchNode = $dom->getElementsByTagName( "FIELD" ); 
foreach( $searchNode as $searchNode ) 
{
    $key = $searchNode->getAttribute('KEY');
    $value = $searchNode->nodeValue; 
    $ARR_OUTPUT[$key]=$value;
}
echo "<pre>";
print_r($ARR_OUTPUT);
```

**OUTPUT :**

```
Array
(
    [status] => 1
    [auth_code] => DEMO43
    [auth_response] => APPROVED
    [avs_code] => X
    [cvv2_code] =>  
    [order_id] => 12345678900015
    [reference_number] => 47210
    [error] => 
    [available_balance] => 
    [is_partial] => 0
    [partial_amount] => 0
    [partial_id] => 
    [original_full_amount] => 
    [outstanding_balance] => 0
)
```

Comment: Awesome! This fixed the problem.  Thank you for the prompt response! This makes perfect sense.  I'm not sure why I couldn't find anything else that would work.